# Show notification after clicking on save to CSV button, if flash player is not installed

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, datatables, message

I am using datatables. I want to show if, there is no flash player in my machine and if I click on the save to CSV button, then one alert box will appear to notify me that there is no flash player in your machine.

I am trying by the following code:

```
if (navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] == undefined){
  alert("No Flash Player");
  return false;
}
```

Is there any direct option in datatables?

I want to show a notification before save to CSV file in datatables.

My save to CSV button is like:

```
<div class="DTTT_container"><a class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_csv" id="ToolTables_data-table_0"><span>Save to CSV</span><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 77px; height: 30px; z-index: 99;"><embed id="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_1" src="/apachedev/xenia/public/js/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="77" height="30" name="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_1" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="id=1&amp;width=77&amp;height=30" wmode="transparent"></div></a></div>
```

which is created by datatbles. And if I want to show a simple alert box after clicking the save to CSV button, then also it is not showing.

```
$('.DTTT_button_csv').click(function(){
           alert("dsada");
           return false;
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Try:

```
var hasFlash = false;
try {
  var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
  if(fo) hasFlash = true;
}catch(e){
  if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) hasFlash = true;
}
```

or

You can use this jQuery plugin : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqplugin.

Usage (if the plugin /mimetype is enabled the properties returns true, otherwise returns false):

```
jQuery.browser.flash //Flash
jQuery.browser.sl //Silverlight
jQuery.browser.pdf //PDF format
jQuery.browser.java //Java
jQuery.browser.qtime //Quicktime
jQuery.browser.wmp //Windows Media Player
jQuery.browser.shk //Shockwave
jQuery.browser.rp //Realplayer
```